# Activate the Workbook containing the code

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to activate active workbook after UNAPP macros, but (if many workbooks are opened) activating always last opened workbook and every time is toggling (last workbook to Activeworkbook), I need to activate ALWAYS the workbook from which code is called.

```
Sub App()
    With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .DisplayAlerts = False
      .EnableEvents = False
      .Calculation = xlManual
      .Visible = False
    End With
End Sub

Sub unApp()
    With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .DisplayAlerts = True
      .EnableEvents = True
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub

Sub testActivate()
    Set wbT = ThisWorkbook
    App
    unApp
    wbT.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question again? Your heading says something else than your description.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, is not a good idea to use `.Activate`. In my opinion the best way to indirect with Workbooks is to set workbooks in variables and then use that variable in a `With Statement`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")

    With wb2
        'Close is just an example
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't need to close workbook, and do not know how many books are opened

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin `.Close` is just an example as you can see in the code. Moreover, assign workbook to a variable is the best approach to use a work to avoid `.Activate`

Answer (score 0):

`Application` affects all workbooks within the current Application so I assume you have multiple Applications open and want to refer to the one where the code is running?

If so you can use

```
With ThisWorkbook.Application
```

(which is good practice anyway)